# How to display a view from a seperate class as a child view controller in a primary view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Trying to show the view of a separate class as a subview of a primary view. Having issues doing this as it seems to be crashing.

Thanks!

Comment: Share some more details like code or what you've done. This will help us solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of this is below.

```
Yourotherclass* object = [[Yourotherclass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,40)];
[self addChildViewController:object];
[object didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:object];
```

This will make the view of the other class populate the current view controller at the co ordinates set at the CGRectMake.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think Rashad is right. You need to share more details.`UIView` can be used as many time in single controller with its own children and positioning.